# Displaying Nested json Data in Drop Down - cshtml javascript json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am looking for a way to "cleanly" display json data in a drop down.

The object I receive looks something like this:

```
"Outer": [
    {
      "Inner1": "Some text here.",
      "Inner2": true,
      "Inner3": false,
      "Inner4": true,
      "Inner5": "A1",
      "Inner6": "Another String"
    },
    {
      "Inner1": "Some text here.",
      "Inner2": true,
      "Inner3": false,
      "Inner4": true,
      "Inner5": "B1",
      "Inner6": "Another String"
    },
    {
      "Inner1": "Some text here.",
      "Inner2": true,
      "Inner3": false,
      "Inner4": true,
      "Inner5": "C1",
      "Inner6": "Another String"
    }
  ]
```

When I put it in a regular select drop down there would be just three lines with all "inner" data shown as one big concatenated string which makes sense but is not quite what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is my drop down:

`<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label>
            MyLabelTextHere
            <select class="col-sm-10" name="item" ng-model="item">
                <option ng-repeat="item in outer" value="{{outer}}" title="{{item}}">{{item}}></option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>`

I would like it to be shown in a way where inner 3 objects are still distinguishable from each other and I will need to see the field names as well as the values for them.

I hope that is enough detail for the question. I am open to any suggestions. Thanks for your time! Any input is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your option tag, just put the values you want explicitly like:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <label>
        MyLabelTextHere
        <select class="col-sm-10" name="item" ng-model="item">
            <option ng-repeat="item in outer" value="{{outer}}" title="{{item}}">
            Inner 1: {{ item.Inner1 }} - Inner 2: {{ item.Inner2 }} 
            </option>
        </select>
    </label>
</td>
```

and format however you like. But beware, you can't use styling or html tags inside a select box.  You'll need something more custom to achieve that, I've used angular bootstrap UI to achieve something like that.

If the keys are inconsistent or something, you can just add a second ng-repeat and iterate over the object like:

```
<ng-repeat="key, val in item">
```

or write a function that takes the object and outputs the formatted string and you'd do:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in outer" value="{{outer}}" title="{{item}}" ng-bind="formatMyObject(item)"></option>
```

and in your controller just have a function like:

```
$scope.formatMyObject = function(item) { 
    //format the object into a string here, do whatever
    return item.Inner1 + " - " + item.Inner2;
};
```